# Marble windows compilation

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, mingw32, marble

I'am trying to compile Marble on Windows 10 using Mingw and Qt 5.5.

```
g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I'am following official [instruction](https://techbase.kde.org/Projects/Marble/WindowsCompiling#Compiling_Marble_using_MinGW_and_mingw32-make). However, I'am getting compilation error:

```
F:\marble\marble\src\lib\marble\MarbleZip.cpp:371:1: warning: 'Marble::MarbleZipReader::FileInfo::FileInfo()' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 MarbleZipReader::FileInfo::FileInfo()
 ^
F:\marble\marble\src\lib\marble\MarbleZip.cpp:376:1: warning: 'Marble::MarbleZipReader::FileInfo::~FileInfo()' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 MarbleZipReader::FileInfo::~FileInfo()
 ^
F:\marble\marble\src\lib\marble\MarbleZip.cpp:380:1: warning: 'Marble::MarbleZipReader::FileInfo::FileInfo(const Marble::MarbleZipReader::FileInfo&)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 MarbleZipReader::FileInfo::FileInfo(const FileInfo &other)
 ^
F:\marble\marble\src\lib\marble\MarbleZip.cpp:385:28: warning: 'Marble::MarbleZipReader::FileInfo& Marble::MarbleZipReader::FileInfo::operator=(const Marble::MarbleZipReader::FileInfo&)' redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage
 MarbleZipReader::FileInfo& MarbleZipReader::FileInfo::operator=(const FileInfo &other)
                            ^
F:\marble\marble\src\lib\marble\MarbleZip.cpp:398:6: warning: 'bool Marble::MarbleZipReader::FileInfo::isValid() const' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 bool MarbleZipReader::FileInfo::isValid() const
      ^
[ 46%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/cloudsync/CloudSyncManager.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/cloudsync/RouteSyncManager.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/cloudsync/OwncloudSyncBackend.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/cloudsync/CloudRouteModel.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/cloudsync/CloudRoutesDialog.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/cloudsync/RouteItem.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/cloudsync/RouteItemDelegate.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/cloudsync/BookmarkSyncManager.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/cloudsync/MergeItem.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/cloudsync/ConflictDialog.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/MarbleWebView.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/TinyWebBrowser.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/MarbleDBusInterface.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/qrc_libmarble.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/qrc_marble.cpp.obj
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/marblewidget-qt5_automoc.cpp.obj
[ 48%] Linking CXX shared library libmarblewidget-qt5.dll
CMakeFiles\marblewidget-qt5.dir/objects.a(NewstuffModel.cpp.obj):NewstuffModel.cpp:(.text+0x8a42): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Marble15MarbleZipReader8FileInfoD1Ev'
CMakeFiles\marblewidget-qt5.dir/objects.a(NewstuffModel.cpp.obj):NewstuffModel.cpp:(.text+0x8aaf): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6Marble15MarbleZipReader8FileInfoD1Ev'
F:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\marblewidget-qt5.dir/objects.a(NewstuffModel.cpp.obj): bad reloc address 0x4 in section `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src\lib\marble\CMakeFiles\marblewidget-qt5.dir\build.make:17541: recipe for target 'src/lib/marble/libmarblewidget-qt5.dll' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [src/lib/marble/libmarblewidget-qt5.dll] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1254: recipe for target 'src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [src/lib/marble/CMakeFiles/marblewidget-qt5.dir/all] Error 2
makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It's looks like there is some problems with with zlib, I was trying to specify path to zlib (compiled manually by myself with Mingw) via CMake GUI, but result was the same - error at linking libmarblewidget-qt5.dll. So... Is anybody know how can I fix it?

Comment: What is CMake's output concerning zlib?

Comment: It should be caused by missing includes, not missing libraries. It is not a linker error, but a compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file "MarbleZipReader.h", change

```
struct Q_GUI_EXPORT FileInfo
```

to

```
struct MARBLE_EXPORT FileInfo
```

This worked for me, but not sure if it is perfectly correct. I assume this will be patched at some stage. I was using Marble branch "Application/15.12".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user5792278's answer the linking error of the question can be solved. However, you may encounter additional linking errors (concerning `libz`). In my case this was with the versions `Application/15.12` + `Qt5.5` + `GCC4.9.2`:

> CMakeFiles\marblewidget-qt5.dir/objects.a(MarbleZip.cpp.obj):MarbleZip.cpp:(.text+[...]): undefined reference to inflateInit2_ [...]

a quick (though not necessarily clean) hack to resolve this, is to replace
the line

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (${MARBLEWIDGET} astro)
```

with

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (${MARBLEWIDGET} astro z)
```

in the file `sources\src\lib\marble\CMakeLists.txt`